# Can we SEF enable to joomla administration?

Tags: joomla, administration, sef

Is it possible to enable SEF to joomla administration? If yes, how we need to proceed on this?
OR is there any .htaccess file to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, by design.

If you need it, you can start by studying how the router.php works in the frontend, but it will be fairly hard to implement.

If you need SEF urls for *some* of your administrative tasks such as writing articles, you might want to consider that Joomla! itself offers front-end editing, and an extensive ACL to limit the access to different groups.  This will also be easier and safer for the users.

Finally, extensions on the JED allow you to offer more administrative tasks through the frontend such as frontpage ordering etc., I haven't used any so I can't recommend a product.